# How to pass a Byte Array into a C++ DLL from vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to call this C DLL function from my vb.net application:

```
HRESULT WINAPI MyTestFunc(BYTE *ByteDef );
Parameters
ByteDef The length of this array is variable.
ByteDef[0] Range from 3 to 5.
ByteDef[1] Range from 1 to 8.
ByteDef[2] Range from 1 to 15.
ByteDef[3] Range from 1 to 8. It must be 2 (8 bit data).
```

The first question is how do I define this function in my vb.net application?
I have tried the following:

```
Declare Function MyTestFunc Lib "xxx.dll" (ByVal ByteDef As Byte()) As Integer
```

The second question is how do I pass the barcodedef parameter to it?
I have tried it as follows:

```
ByteDef = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("3422", 0, 4)
Result = MyTestFunc(ByteDef)
```

This keeps coming back with an error message from the function the the bar-code definition is invalid.

Comment: Try changing the parameter to `ByVal ByteDef As Byte`.

Comment: @JimHewitt : Then it is no longer a byte array. Mapping `BYTE*` to `Byte()` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Actually I meant `ByRef ByteDef As Byte`.

Comment: The declaration is just fine.  Exactly how you are supposed to initialize the array, that's anybody's guess.  Certainly not with Encoding.GetBytes().  If the manual doesn't make sense then use a telephone to contact the author or vendor.

Comment: @JimHewitt : That still doesn't make it a _**byte array**_, which is what the OP needs. As I (and Hans) said, `ByVal ByteDef As Byte()` is perfectly fine.

Comment: The declaration is a pointer to Byte.  Actually I think both will work.

Comment: @JimHewitt : In general they both work, yes. But `ByRef ... As Byte` will not work for _what the OP needs it for_. In his first code block it is explicitly stated that `ByteDef` is an array.

Comment: @JimHewitt, Since the OP needs a byte array I have toe use ByVal ByteDef As Byte() in the definition. I also tries ByteDef = New Byte() {3, 4, 2, 2} to convert the values to a bytearray. I still get the same error "The ByteDef definition is invalid".

Comment: @MohamedAsadi : _You_ are the OP ;). OP means _Original Poster_. -- My suggested solution is the correct way of creating such an array however, so if it still says that it's incorrect you'll have to contact the author of the original C++ code and ask them for guidance on _**what data**_ to pass to the function. Alternatively try calling the function from a C++ project, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
ByteDef = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("3422", 0, 4)
```

You cannot convert a string into a byte array like that because a number ***character*** is not the same as an ***actual number***. For instance the character `"3"` is actually represented by `51` in byte form.

A simple verification of your resulting array would've shown you this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/R3Qcuq

In the end you should ***NEVER*** convert a string into a byte array ***if** you require it to hold **specific** bytes*. Strings are strings, and byte arrays are byte arrays. Keep them apart *unless* you have a good reason to convert to one or the other.

In your case the solution is simple, just initialize a new byte array with the bytes that you need:

```
ByteDef = New Byte() {3, 4, 2, 2}
```